# Reset element to "default" event

Tags: javascript

In Javascript, how can you set the event handler of a DOM element to default behavior?

For example, suppose I set the `onkeypress` event of an input element:

```
elem.onkeypress = function() { alert("Key pressed!"); }
```

Later, how can I remove this event?  Is it okay to simply set the `onkeypress` property to null?  I tried that and it works, but I don't know if it is the proper way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that the events will be `undefined` rather than `null`, so you'd be better off setting back to that.

It's probably overkill, but to be more robust, you're arguably better off keeping a reference to whatever used to be registered to the `onkeypress` event & reassign that (just in case some other script is trying to use it too). So:

```
var oldKeyPress = elem.onkeypress;
elem.onkeypress = function() { alert("Key pressed!"); }

//... later ...

elem.onkeypress = oldKeyPress;
```